# How to store and manage singular data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, content-management-system, content-management

I'm developing a site with Ruby on Rails. I have data on layout that doesn't repeat more then once. And I need to enable content-menegers to change it easily. I could create a model or several models for them and let content-managers edit it in RailsAdmin. But I doubt I should use models that way because entities of such models will be ment to exist in singular number. I mean there aren't multple site names, logos, backgrounds, welcoming texts, etc. But I want to enable them to be edited in a web-interface or equally comfortable not worrying about the cache and not looking at code and serfing through complicated directories structure.

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: You could use YAML, which Ruby/Rails has lots of support for. It's used, for example, in some of the Rails config files (`.yml`).

Comment: Yes, but that requires serfing for directory structure and working with code. We asume that content-managers have low computer skills and can(or want to) only work with nice GUI.

Comment: OK, it's a little unclear what you're asking, then. I was suggesting using YAML as a format "under the hood" which Ruby/Rails would manage for the user, just like it were in the database. But in this case, you're just managing one set of data (which is what I thought the question was about).

Comment: OK, so there are tools for GUI management of YAML configs like RailsAdmin for models?

Comment: Not as part of Rails. There aren't methods to tie YAML items to GUI entities. If that's what you need, then perhaps a simple one record db table is the way to go.

Comment: It is way to go for sure, but still a concept of the "one-row-table" seems quirky because tables are ment to have multiple rows. That's why I'm asking. It resembles singleton pattern.

Comment: Yes, I do understand what you mean, and it's a good question.